# Dragable window is getting mouse stuck and busy state

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, winui-3

I have maui app with blazor I removed the windows default title bar, I'm creating a custom one with blazor

The code works fine, but the mouse is stuck at the point where it was clicked, it is in the busy state

The application moves normally, but the window is stuck to the mouse.

The code is:

**Blazor:**

```
<div class="bg-default w-full h-3 fixed" @onmousedown="@MoveWindow">
 ....
</div>

@code {

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    const uint MOUSE_MOVE = 0xF012;

    private void MoveWindow()
    {
       var win = App.Current.Windows.First();
       var view = win.Handler.PlatformView;
       IntPtr Handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(view);

       ReleaseCapture();
       DefWindowProc(Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (UIntPtr)MOUSE_MOVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can remove mouse stuck in busy state?

Is there another way to move the maui window other than the code I used?

Comment: If it were a problem with Windows, rebooting should fix it. If it is a hardware problem, you may use another mouse that can  be inserted into the computer to test.